# EF Core Transaction Order and Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

### Issue with EF Core transaction order and foreign key constraint

**Description**

I'm facing an issue with Entity Framework Core while trying to add both a `User` and an `Order` entity in the same transaction. In my application, a `User` can have multiple `Order`s, and each `Order` must have exactly one `User`.

I expect both entities to be created in the correct order - first the `User`, then the `Order`, so the foreign key relationship can be resolved successfully. However, EF Core seems to attempt to create the `Order` before the `User`, leading to a foreign key constraint violation.

**Important Information**

- This issue is part of a simplified version of a domain-driven-design project. It's worth noting that my `Order` entity does not have a navigation property to `User` as they belong to different "domains." I believe that the foreign key `int UserId` should be sufficient for this relationship.
- I have tried calling `SaveChanges()` after adding the `User` to the `DbContext` but BEFORE adding the `Order`, and it works. However, this approach results in two separate transactions, which is not acceptable for my use-case.

**Code**

I have provided a [runnable repository](https://github.com/sander1095/Efentityorderworker) with all the relevant code in `Worker.cs`, `MyDbContext.cs`, `User.cs`, and `Order.cs`. The core of the code looks like this:

```cs
using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
    var user = new User("Test user");
    var order = new Order(user);

    dbContext.Users.Add(user);
    dbContext.Orders.Add(order);

    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

**Stack Traces**

Here are the relevant parts of the stack trace:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
  Executed DbCommand (40ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = Int32), @p1='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT INTO [Order] ([UserId])
  OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id]
  VALUES (@p0);
  INSERT INTO [User] ([Name])
  OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id]
  VALUES (@p1);
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
  An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'Efentityorderworker.MyDbContext'.
  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
   ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Order_User_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "db-eforder-test", table "dbo.User", column 'Id'.
```

I'm looking for advice on how to ensure that EF Core creates the `User` entity before the `Order` entity within the same transaction, considering my domain design and constraints.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: EF will insert the items in the correct order, assuming the *entities* and configuration is correct. You didn't post either the classes or the DbContext configuration though. The SQL code suggests there's no relation between User and Order. Post the relevant code in the question itself

Comment: If `Order` had a `User` property and/or `User` an `Orders`, things would just work. Try creating a working, simple example *before* trying to setup migrations and multi-file type configurations.

Comment: Check the EF Core [Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli) tutorial. It's more complex than your example and yet needs *no* explicit configuration

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did post all the classes and configuration in the runnable repository link :) https://github.com/sander1095/Efentityorderworker

Comment: Post them in *this* question, not a link to something that may disappear in 10 minutes. Without the actual code this question is meaningless. BTW I already explained what's wrong with the missing code. Splitting the configuration in multiple files makes fixing such problems harder too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Order entity does not have a navigation property to User . . . I believe that the foreign key int UserId should be sufficient for this relationship.

That's correct, EF Core supports that. And correctly reorders insert/update/delete operations. As soon as you provide the correct data.

Let take a look at your example:

```cs
var user = new User("Test user");
var order = new Order(user);

dbContext.Users.Add(user);
dbContext.Orders.Add(order);
```

Since you are using only Ids, ask yourself, what is the `user.Id` here

```cs
var order = new Order(user);
```

The answer is 0. And this is what EF is trying to insert and is failing with FK constraint violation.

It can easily be seen if you insert at the end

```cs
var info = dbContext.ChangeTracker.ToDebugString();
```

which will show

```
Order {Id: -2147482647} Added
  Id: -2147482647 PK Temporary
  UserId: 0 FK
User {Id: -2147482647} Added
  Id: -2147482647 PK Temporary
  Name: 'Test user'
```

This is a fundamental issue with new entities with auto generated keys - the actual Id is not available until you call `SaveChanges{Async}`. EF Core actually associates a temporary value to it when you call `Add`, but starting from some version does not apply it to the entity, so the entity property still has value 0, i.e. even you do this

```cs
var user = new User("Test user");
dbContext.Users.Add(user);

// user.Id is still 0
```

Now, this is one of the problems of not having at least one navigation property. If you have so, you would simply set it (or add to the inverse entity collection) and EF navigation property fixup will take care of PKs/FKs and correct order.

Since you don't have any navigation, you have to use ugly workarounds. For instance, to let EF assign temporary Id value to the entity and still keep it marked as temporary, you could use the following:

```cs
var user = new User("Test user");
var userId = dbContext.Add(user).Property(e => e.Id);
// user.Id is 0, userId.CurrentValue is some temp value
userId.IsTemporary = userId.IsTemporary; // <--
// user.Id is now userId.CurrentValue 
 
var order = new Order(user);
dbContext.Add(order);

var info = dbContext.ChangeTracker.ToDebugString();
```

Ugly right? And can break in any future EF version. The only good thing is that now the info shows

```
Order {Id: -2147482647} Added
  Id: -2147482647 PK Temporary
  UserId: -2147482647 FK
User {Id: -2147482647} Added
  Id: -2147482647 PK Temporary
  Name: 'Test user'
```

and `SaveChanges` runs successfully with the log something like this

```
  Executed DbCommand (38ms) [Parameters=[@p0='Test user' (Nullable = false) (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[User] ([Name])
  OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id]
  VALUES (@p0);

  Executed DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[@p1='3'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Order] ([UserId])
  OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id]
  VALUES (@p1);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Order entity does not have a navigation property to User . . . I believe that the foreign key int UserId should be sufficient for this relationship.

Nope.  EF doesn't understand Foreign Key properties without Navigation Properties.  Without a Navigation Property EF will not know how to order the inserts, and you would have to force that by calling SaveChanges multiple times.

Comment: Hey David! Thank you for your reply. In my experience, Foreign Key Properties without Navigation properties have worked fine and are supported by the Fluent API for a long time with no problems. However, this is the first time it has caused issues. Do you know anything about some official docs/resources that support your claim? That way I can dig in a bit deeper.

Comment: @S.tenBrinke you misunderstood what was happening in older projects then. In the (still missing) code there are no relations defined in the DbContext. There's half a relation in a class that may or may not be loaded. EF *doesn't* inspect the database at runtime, it only uses the conventions and relations configured in the code itself.